# Search a specific code in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have some "codes" that I get from database and sort them in tables in php. All the codes which begin with the number 1 in the first array, all the codes which begin with 2 in the second.. till 9.

```
Array
(
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1264
        [1] => 1264536
        [2] => 1264537
        [3] => 1264538
 )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 213
        [1] => 21320
        [2] => 21321
        [3] => 21322          
)...
```

the code

```
function getCodes($codeEgr){

$oneTable = array();
$twoTable = array();
$threeTable = array();
$fourTable = array();
$fiveTable = array();
$sixTable = array();
$sevenTable = array();
$eightTable = array();
$nineTable = array();

foreach($codeEgr as $row)
{
        list($destination,$codeTegr,$price,$effectiveDate) = $row;
        $code = $codeTegr;            
        $first = substr($code,0,1);

        switch($first)
        {
                case 1:
                        $oneTable[] = $code;
                        break;
                case 2:
                        $twoTable[] = $code;
                        break;
                case 3:
                        $threeTable[] = $code;
                        break;
                case 4:
                        $fourTable[] = $code;
                        break;
                case 5:
                        $fiveTable[] = $code;
                        break;
                case 6:
                        $sixTable[] = $code;
                        break;
                case 7:
                        $sevenTable[] = $code;
                        break;
                case 8:
                        $eightTable[] = $code;
                        break;
                case 9:
                        $nineTable[] = $code;
                        break;
        }
}

$codeTable = array(1 => $oneTable,2 => $twoTable,3 => $threeTable,4 => $fourTable,5 => $fiveTable,
6 => $sixTable,7 => $sevenTable,8 => $eightTable,9 => $nineTable);
return $codeTable;
```

}

What I want to do know is to find a code in this array(). Per example if I have a code like 156545 I search the codes only in the fist array and not the others. If I have a code like 265456 I search in the second array...
And after return true or false If found or not

I dont know how to do in php Im a beginner for the loops

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: You guys should start posting the actual array instead of the array result.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a simple approach:

```
$code= 123123;
$first = substr($code,0,1);

    switch($first)
    {
            case 1:
                    $key = array_search($code, $oneTable);
                    break;
            case 2:
                     $key = array_search($code, $twoTable);
                    break;
            and so on...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I also refactored the code for you

```
function getCodes($codeEgr){
    $codes = array();

    foreach($codeEgr as $row)
    {
            list($destination,$codeTegr,$price,$effectiveDate) = $row;
            $code = $codeTegr;            
            $first = $code[0]; // get first digit of code string

            $codes[$first][] = $code;
    }

    return $codes;
}

function searchCode($codesArr, $code){
    $firstDigit = $code[0];

    $searchIn = (isset($codesArr[$firstDigit])) ? $codesArr[$firstDigit] : array();

    return array_search($code, $searchIn)
}
```